# Android touch issue

Tags: android

I have an imageview inside a layout. When I touch the view in the emulator it's taking more than one event. Why? Please tell me what the problem is.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry sandhya but I can't understand your question. Maybe you want to rephrase it a little bit. What are you trying to do and what events does the imageview take?

Answer (score 0):

Is it ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP? Can you dump the MotionEvent and check the type using logcat?